# Is it possible to continue to debug from the previous position after modifying my code without restarting the debug session?

Tags: perl, debugging, komodo

I use Komodo as the IDE to develop my Perl programs.But every time I start to debug, the debugger takes nearly 15 seconds to start. It is frustrating to wait, so I wonder if it is possible to continue the debug without restarting the session? That is to say, if I step to line 99 in my previous debug, and then modify some code after line 99, is it possible to continue debugging from line 99?

Answer (score 2):

The entire program has to be recompiled after you modify your code, so no, it isn't possible to edit the program and then continue your debug session. You have to restart.

Note that in Komodo the breakpoints are persistent, so you can place a breakpoint before you restart the program, and then run to the breakpoint before you continue working. I wouldn't have thought fifteen seconds was too bad unless you are making tiny changes and restarting every minute or two. You should fix as much as you can at one time.

The only IDE I know that has this facility is Microsoft's Visual C, and it doesn't always work then. There are probably others, but Perl isn't one of them.

Comment: Also note that you should be able to edit variables while debugging. So whilst you cannot change your actual code while debugging, you can still do a little bit of interactive testing by changing variables.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `R' to restart the program while debugging with `-d' option, like `perl -d test.pl`, but I don't know if Komodo has a solution.

It's better to figure out why it takes so much time to start debugging.

Comment: R restarts, he asked without restart

Comment: @nrathaus R doesn't "restarting the [debugging] session", understand?